# SearchView.setSearchableInfo crashes due to some mistake in Manifest

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest, manifest, searchview

I'm trying to add a SearchView to the action bar on MainActivity. I created *res/xml/searchable.xml* and another activity *SearchResultsActivity* to handle search. However when these 2 lines of code in the MainActivity are executed, the app crashes:

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity"
             />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that you import the correct SearchView, are you using sherlock actionbar? Also please provide LogCat output.

Comment: I'm not using sherlock action bar. I import android.app.Actionbar.

Comment: I found my mistake while posting you the LogCat output. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my mistake while checking LogCat output, as **cYrixmorten** suggested. In menu layout *main.xml*, I wrote

```
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

instead of

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

And the problem was the SearchView class couldn't be found.